# Java ClientAuth SSL connection fails

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have a Java based client which talks to my Java server via Tomcat 8.  I need to get ClientAuth SSL working between the client and server.  I have 2 different problems depending on whether I configure Tomcat to use Http11NioProtocol for SSL or native APR (openssl) for SSL.  I need either Tomcat config to work.  I tried both to narrow down the problem.

Client code is below.  I switched to using custom X509ExtendedTrustManager (ServerTrustManager) and X509ExtendedKeyManager (ClientAuthKeyManager) classes in order to ensure the proper data is provided and to help debug.

```
ServerTrustManager serverTm = new ServerTrustManager(getCaCertificates());
TrustManager [] trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { serverTm };
                ClientAuthKeyManager mykm = 
                        new ClientAuthKeyManager(getSessionContext().getProductAgentCertificate(), getSessionContext());
KeyManager[] keyManagers = new KeyManager[] { mykm };

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createDefault();
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
Client clientHttps = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .withConfig(getClientConfig())
                    .sslContext(sslContext)
                    .build();
```

**TOMCAT WITH APR (OPENSSL)**

Tomcat 8 configured with:

```
<Connector port="8443"  
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
SSLEnabled="true" 
SSLVerifyClient="require"
SSLCertificateFile="...\dim.magnicomp.com-productserver.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile="...\dim.magnicomp.com-productserver.key" 
SSLPassword="..."
SSLCertificateChainFile="...\ca-bundle.crt"
maxThreads="200" 
scheme="https" 
secure="true"/>
```

**QUESTION:** Is there debug output/logging I can enable for the Apr/OpenSSL code?  I couldn't find any results from google on this.

With this Tomcat config my Java client fails to connect (ssl debug from client):

```
... snip ...
*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 264
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()
17:05:17,709 ERROR JAX-RS ProcessingException for https://dim.magnicomp.com:8443/cabridge/v1/device/configuration - java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

With this same config the "openssl s_client ..." command with the ClientAuth cert works:

```
# openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -CAfile ca-bundle.crt -cert dim.magnicomp.com-productagent.crt -key dim.magnicomp.com-productagent.key
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 CN = MagniComp Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 DC = com, DC = magnicomp, CN = MagniComp Issuing CA3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = dim.magnicomp.com
verify return:1
write:errno=113
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=dim.magnicomp.com
   i:/DC=com/DC=magnicomp/CN=MagniComp Issuing CA3
 1 s:/DC=com/DC=magnicomp/CN=MagniComp Issuing CA3
   i:/CN=MagniComp Root CA
 2 s:/CN=MagniComp Root CA
   i:/CN=MagniComp Root CA
---
... snip ...
```

**TOMCAT WITH Http11NioProtocol**

The Tomcat side appears to fail to accept the ClientAuth cert (output from Tomcat/Apr):

```
http-nio-8443-exec-2, fatal error: 46: General SSLEngine problem
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
http-nio-8443-exec-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
```

The above Tomcat errors occur from either my Java client or "openssl s_connect":

```
# openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -CAfile ca-bundle.crt -cert dim.magnicomp.com-productagent.crt -key dim.magnicomp.com-productagent.key
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 CN = MagniComp Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 DC = com, DC = magnicomp, CN = MagniComp Issuing CA3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = dim.magnicomp.com
verify return:1
6870300:error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:s3_pkt.c:1472:SSL alert number 46
6870300:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=dim.magnicomp.com
   i:/DC=com/DC=magnicomp/CN=MagniComp Issuing CA3
 1 s:/DC=com/DC=magnicomp/CN=MagniComp Issuing CA3
   i:/CN=MagniComp Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... snip ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=dim.magnicomp.com
issuer=/DC=com/DC=magnicomp/CN=MagniComp Issuing CA3
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/CN=MagniComp Root CA
/DC=com/DC=magnicomp/CN=MagniComp Issuing CA3
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:RSA+MD5
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4528 bytes and written 5835 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 57102D9B932A1CBBCEFB687A74885A204D3473D8154EBA09D8E073173B18CC17
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 9BDC26F7CD11D05F2EFF07764F280D167E1547306B6626EF9955C97805816A13F7A0ABB9CCC3BF883282998881DDFFB3
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1460678043
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

The Tomcat server.xml:

```
<Connector 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
SSLEnabled="true" 
clientAuth="true" 
keyAlias="privatekey" 
keyPass="..."
keystoreFile="...\dim.magnicomp.com-productserver.jks" 
keystorePass="..."
keystoreType="JKS"
maxThreads="200" 
port="8443" 
scheme="https"
secure="true" 
truststoreFile="...\cacerts.jks" 
truststorePass="changeit"/>
```

**DEV ENVIRONMENT**
I'm using Oracle Java 1.8.65.  I have installed the full JCE in the JVM and verified its enabled.  The Agent and server are the same Windows 10 system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the APR environment you haven't configured OpenSSL to trust any certificate authorities. You need to set either

   ```
   SSLCACertificatePath
   ```

   or

   ```
   SSLCACertificateFile
   ```

   See the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support).
2. In the non-APR case, your truststore doesn't trust the client certificate. If it is self-signed it needs to be imported into the truststore, which implies you should copy the JDK/JRE truststore to a local one and import into that so you don't get clobbered by the next Java update. If it isn't self-signed, the CA's certificate needs to be imported as above. In both case the `keytool -trustcacerts` option must be used.

Comment: Yes, the SSLCACertificatePath for the APR config was just what I was missing.  I had it confused with the SSLCertificateChainFile which I realize now is meant for the SSLCertificateFile.  Thank you EJP!!!!!